# PHP soap ssl authentication with proxy server

Tags: php, soap, proxy, soap-client

I'm trying to integrate soap service using PHP. For this service, we have 2 level of authentication.

1. Ip based
2. SSL-based authentication

I can able to use SOAP proxy and SSL separately. but it's not working together.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
       'local_cert' => 'ssl_certificate.pem',
       'passphrase' => '********'
    ]
]);

$client = new WSSoapClient(
     'local_wsdl_file.wsdl',
    [
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'location' => 'soap_end_point',
        'proxy_host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'proxy_port' => '3128',
        'proxy_login' => 'username',
        'proxy_password' => 'password',
        'stream_context' => $context
    ]
);
```

is it possible to use ssl authentication through proxy server?